# How to specify a local file system in git diff?

Tags: git

As I see “git diff” shows the difference between my local file system and my local git repository.  I also can find the difference between my local repository and a remote repository:

```
git diff develop remotes/origin/develop
```

How to find the difference between the local file system and remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the branch name and it will use your working directory

```
git diff remotes/origin/develop
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote will work. Just keep in mind that `remotes/origin/develop` is actually your local copy of the remote repository. Git won't update it automatically. You can do it manually with `git fetch origin`.